# How to disconnect android device from chromecast if onApplicationDisconnected was called

Tags: android, chromecast

I have an application which allows to stream content to chromecast. According to app logic only one device can be connected to chromecast

When we connecting to receiver we are using:

```
Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions
                .builder(mSelectedDevice, mCastClientListener);
GoogleApiClient mApiClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener)
            .build();
mApiClient.connect();
```

when chromecast is connected succesfully, we launch reciever

```
Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, mChromeCastAppId, true)
      .setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
                 @Override
                 public void nResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
                        //do logic when successfully connected
                 }
            }
       });
```

If other sender connects to device, that is already controlled by first device and playing stream, it restarts reciever and first device gets 2005 error in `onApplicationDisconnected` callback, but the MediaRouteButton still have a status like it’s connected to device. And I found no methods to reset route.
If I tap MediaRouteButton, I can see the dialog, that allows me to control volume and to disconnect from the chromecast.

That's confusing for the user. How can I reset MediaRouteButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call:

```
mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute())
```